# Moving podcasts from Catalina podcasts app to music?

Tags: catalina, music.app, podcasts.app

I subscribe to a set of podcasts in which each "episode" is a song. I want to convert the episodes into songs in my music library. Prior to Catalina, this was [straightforward](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6050904). I'd edit the podcasts to change the "media kind" from podcast to music, then edit a couple other metadata fields.

Now with Catalina, iTunes has been split into separate music and podcasts apps. I can start the podcasts app and select a "show" to see the episodes for a podcast. From there, the first thing I tried was to drag several episodes into the music app.

First of all, dragging more than about ten episodes at once causes the podcasts app to crash. I suppose that's a bug which Apple will eventually fix.

Dragging a small number of episodes into the music app does indeed import the file into music. But absolutely none of the metadata for the episode is retained. The only metadata field which is filled in is the song title, which is set from the filename including the ".mp3" extension:

[image]

Does anyone know of a practical way to save podcast episodes as music on Catalina, preserving the information about the episode which was provided by the publisher?

Edit: Actually, importing into the music app didn't work at all. the Music app recorded the file's location as ".../iTunes%20Music/Podcasts/KEXP%20Song%20of%20the%20Day/Squid%20-%20Match%20Bet.mp3", i.e. the location of the podcast app's copy of the file. And the music app seems to think the song is zero length for some reason.

Comment: This isn't an answer in general, but for the KEXP Song of the Day podcast specifically, I go to the [RSS Feed](https://omny.fm/shows/kexp-song-of-the-day) and download the songs through my browser. They open into Music by default.